# How to evenly split two SKSpriteNodes on a game scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, cgpoint

I am trying to achieve the following result. 2 `SKSpriteNode` objects added as child nodes to a `GameScene` which take up full width. I have limited my scope to not deal with `landscape` mode for now and would like to size the `height` of each background at `50%` (based off current view size).

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let background1 = SKSpriteNode()
        background1.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
        background1.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0,y:0.0)
        background1.size = view.bounds.size

        let background2 = SKSpriteNode()
        background2.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
        background2.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0,y:0.0)
        background2.size = view.bounds.size

        self.addChild(background1)
        self.addChild(background2)
    }
```

I am having some trouble understanding how the `position` property works in accordance with `CGPoint` as neither `SKNode` currently shows up for me. Does anyone know if the SpriteKit offers and elastic sizing capability so that I don't have to hardcode the the coordinates for `CGPoint(x:?,y:?`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place the nodes at the same point on the screen regardless of the device you should do something like this:

```
myNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))//places node at middle of screen
```

There is also GetMaxX, GetMaxY and so on. If you cmd + click on a method in Xcode, you will see more methods like it. You can also get the max x or y and multiply by a decimal value if you want to place the node at a more specific point on the screen. Happy coding.